# How to communicate about not giving a wedding gift to friends who haven't held their party yet?

Tags: friends, indonesia, weddings

We are a group of close friends. Two months ago, two of our friends got married. Usually we give a gift to them when they hold a party. But, because of the coronavirus, they didn't hold any party, just a basic ceremony. We couldn't attend and couldn't give any gift. They have said they'll give a party at a later time, but there is no exact date yet.

Now, the situation is much better, another friend is getting married, and she will hold a wedding party (already allowed by government). We have plans to attend it and give a gift.

The problem is, how we can act fair and communicate this to the two friends that we didn't give a gift? We don't want to hurt their feelings.

Comment: Hey bongaloo, do you know if those two friends who already got married are planning in doing a party later?

Comment: Also, in what country are you? Answers might change a lot depending on the culture.

Comment: Hey. No, they said they will do later, but there is no exact date.
I am from Indonesia

Comment: Would there be a problem with sending a gift to their place instead of handing it over at the party? Is it some type of “honor” related custom?

Comment: You said you already asked your friends if they'd give a party, and they said they'd do so later... Are you in a position where you could ask them again if this is still the case/if they know more already about the plans? Are you planning to attend this later party, and give them a gift then? What makes you think 'just' being honest and promising them a gift when they give their party won't work/will hurt their feelings?

Comment: What stop you from telling them exactly what you are telling us ? If they are good friends, they wouldn't take bad you saying "Hey, I still didn't give you your wedding gift as I thought about giving it during the party like [other friend]. But covid and everything happened... Did you manage to plan another date yet ?"

Answer (score 1):

In France (where I am from), there is this social rule that you only give gifts to people who invited you to the celebration (birthday, christening, marriage, etc...) or gave you a gift linked to said celebration. So, basically, gift-giving is for reciprocating something. It's a way to thank someone for spending money or time on you.

Furthermore, the value of the gift *needs* to be related to how much the person spends on you. So, if someone helped you with a small favor, you can reciprocate by giving them a small gift, but it would be considered bad etiquette/rude to give them something of too much value (because then, they will be the one feeling like they have an obligation toward *you*).

I don't know what the culture is in Indonesia, but if it's similar to France and taking into account that your friends have "said they'll give a party at a later time", here is what I would do:

When the topic of the wedding is brought up, casually asked your friend if they know when they will be doing their wedding party. Then say something like:

> I can't wait to have the party so that I can finally give you your gifts!

By doing that, your friends will be reassured that you are still planning to give them a gift and that you are simply waiting for the party to do so.

If it turns out your friends won't do a party after all, then according to the (French) social etiquette, you can still give them a small gift. You just need to make sure that it's noticeably smaller than if there had been a party.